# Javascript Neural Network Weight List Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, networking, backpropagation

I have written a tiny Neural Network in JavaScript and moving from C# irritates me a ton since JavaScript is in my opinion way buggier. I fixed the original error which was happening but now I can't even back propagate since the weights and biases go to NaN after the process!

Why does my BackPropagation Function cause weights to go NaN

```
class NeuralNet {
// const for learningRate
static LEARNING_RATE = 0.33;
// define float[][] for biases
biases;
// define float[][] for values
values;
// define float[][] for errors
errors;
// define float[][][] for weights
weights;

// constructor
constructor(inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize) {
    // set biases
    this.biases = [
        // hidden layer
        new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0).map(NeuralNet.random),
        // output layer
        new Array(outputSize).fill(0).map(NeuralNet.random)
    ];
    // set values
    this.values = [
        // input layer
        new Array(inputSize).fill(0),
        // hidden layer
        new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0),
        // output layer
        new Array(outputSize).fill(0)
    ];
    // set errors
    this.errors = [
        // hidden layer
        new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0).map(() => new Array(inputSize).fill(0)),
        // output layer
        new Array(outputSize).fill(0).map(() => new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0))
    ];
    // set weights
    this.weights = [
        // hidden layer
        new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0).map(() => new Array(inputSize).fill(0).map(NeuralNet.random)),
        // output layer
        new Array(outputSize).fill(0).map(() => new Array(hiddenSize).fill(0).map(NeuralNet.random))
    ];
}

// define a random
static random() {
    // return random number between -1 and 1
    return Math.random() * 2 - 1;
}

// tanh function
static tanh(x) {
    // return tanh of x
    return Math.tanh(x);
}

// tanh activation function
feedForward() {
    // for each layer
    for (var i = 1; i < this.values.length; i++) {
        // for each neuron
        for (var j = 0; j < this.values[i].length; j++) {
            // set value to bias
            this.values[i][j] = this.biases[i - 1][j];
            // for each weight
            for (var k = 0; k < this.weights[i - 1].length; k++) {
                // add weight * value
                this.values[i][j] += this.weights[i - 1][k][j] * this.values[i][k];
            }
            // apply tanh
            this.values[i][j] = NeuralNet.tanh(this.values[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// get output of neural net
getOutput(inpts) {
    // set input
    this.setInput(inpts);
    // feed forward
    this.feedForward();
    // return the output
    return this.values[this.values.length - 1];
}

// backpropagation that doesn't make all values NaN
backpropagation(expected) {
    // for each layer
    for (var i = this.values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // for each neuron
        for (var j = 0; j < this.values[i].length; j++) {
            // if output layer
            if (i == this.values.length - 1) {
                // set error
                this.errors[i - 1][j] = (expected[j] - this.values[i][j]) * (1 - this.values[i][j] * this.values[i][j]);
            } else {
                // set error
                this.errors[i - 1][j] = 0;
                // for each weight
                for (var k = 0; k < this.weights[i].length; k++) {
                    // add weight * error
                    this.errors[i - 1][j] += this.weights[i][k][j] * this.errors[i][k];
                }
                // multiply error with tanh
                this.errors[i - 1][j] *= (1 - this.values[i][j] * this.values[i][j]);
            }
            // for each weight
            for (var k = 0; k < this.weights[i - 1].length; k++) {
                // add error * value * learning rate
                this.weights[i - 1][k][j] += this.errors[i - 1][j] * this.values[i - 1][k] * NeuralNet.LEARNING_RATE;
            }
            // add error * learning rate
            this.biases[i - 1][j] += this.errors[i - 1][j] * NeuralNet.LEARNING_RATE;
        }
    }
}
```

Init --> var neuralNet = new NeuralNet(10, 10, 1);

Comment: Can you update your question to include the inputs into the constructor, please?

Comment: Yea sure new problem